# Can the word 'freed' be used as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

For example: "Freed memory can be reused by another computer programs"?

Comment: There is a definition for [freed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/freed) that lists it as an adjective.

Comment: @MattЭллен It lists the word 'free' as an adjective, not 'freed'. There is no example using 'freed'

Comment: So it does. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it can. Take for example the poem title [The Latest Freed Man](http://people.zeelandnet.nl/henklensen/stevens.htm), by that stylistic arbiter of elegance himself, Wallace Stevens.

Verbs in the past tense often form adjectives:

> reclaimed land
>   exhausted stores
>   unsated appetites
>   broken bones

And on and on.

**Addendum**

The parts of speech in English have a very chameleon nature (note use of noun *chameleon* as an adjective in this sentence). Now consider this odd journey of a noun to an adjective to a verb to a past-tense verb used as an adjective:

> **mud** (*noun*) *The water was full of mud.*
>   **muddy** (*adjective*) *The water was muddy.*
>   **muddy** (*verb*) *Don't muddy the water!*
>   **muddied** (*verb, past tense*) *Aww, you went and muddied the water, even after I told you not to!*
>   **muddied** (*adjective*) *Now the muddied water makes it impossible to see the fish.*